# Can't cast _InternalLinkedHashMap<Object?, Object?> to anything

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I've been having some issues with get data from Firebase RealtimeDatabase as a Map despite me uploading it as a Map in the first place. All solutions I see are that you should just cast The snapshot.value to the data type incoming but no iteration of that works for me. I've been able to call `toString()` on the snapshot value and I've verified that it's a Map but the compiler doesn't even allow me to cast it to a Map let alone run it. If I try to use dynamic to prevent that compile error, I still get this  `Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<Object?, Object?>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>?' in type cast`.

This is what I've done,

```
  Future<Map<String, dynamic>> getBasicDetail(
      DatabaseReference databaseReference) async {
    DatabaseReference imageURLevent = databaseReference.child('basicDetail');

    final snapShot = await imageURLevent.get();
    return Map<String, dynamic>.from(
        snapShot.value as Map<String, dynamic>? ?? {});
  }

  Future<void> readProfileData({required String userId}) async {

    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref("users/$userId");

    final basicDetail = await getBasicDetail(ref);
    
    // Print the data of the snapshot
    debugPrint(basicDetail.toString());
  }
```

I've tried every possible combination of parsing this data but nothing works. For some reason in examples and videos when you cast the right hand side to `Map<String,dynamic>` you get no error but my IDE doesn't even allow me to do that. I've also tried Map.from() seems to be a popular one that works but mine simple throws a runtime error.

Why does this [image: Firecasts] from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sXBJZD0fBa4&ab_channel=Firebase

work while mine

[image: Code] doesn't?

event.snapshot.value looks valid too

```
[log] {bloodGroup: gh, imageURL: /data/user/0/com.piyushlimited.buzzai/app_flutter/image_picker7287835118545461685.jpg, fullName: Henry Nana Adu, weight: 523, dateOfBirth: 11/11/11, licenseNumber: 256489, age: 28}
```

I can access one value of data by referencing the full path to it but I have a large Map and I can't do it for each and every value in each and every category. It seems costly and time wasting. I've spent days trying a lot of things so please keep that in mind.

Comment: Try once doing this -  snapShot.value as Map<String, dynamic>? ?? <String, dynamic>{});

Comment: What is the value and type event.snapshot.value returning?

Comment: event.snapshot.value returns _InternalLinkedHashMap<Object?, Object?>

Comment: @Diwyansh your advice doesn't work I still get  Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<Object?, Object?>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>?' in type cast

Comment: Can you print  event.snapshot.value and add the print result in your question?

Comment: I have added that

Comment: Try my answer and revert.

Comment: You can't use `as Map<String, dynamic>?` if the object wasn't constructed as a `Map<String, dynamic>` in the first place.  You *must* use `Map.from`.  What runtime error do you get when using `Map.from` *without* using an `as` cast?

Comment: The IDE doesn't allow me to compile without the as cast, as shown in the second picture

Comment: Ah, because `snapShot.value` isn't statically known to be a `Map` at all.  First cast it to a `Map` of its actual runtime type and *then* transform to have your desired key and value types: `Map<String, dynamic>.from(snapShot.value as Map<Object?, Object?>? ?? {})`.

Comment: @jamesdlin If i do that I get `Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<Object?, Object?>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'` idk why

Comment: @jamesdlin I've tried multiple stuff like that even with HashMaps, nothing works

Comment: It sounds like you used `as Map<String, dynamic>`, not `as Map<Object? Object?>` as I suggested.

Comment: @jamesdlin yes it does sound like that but I did in fact do it your way. Anyways I've found a solution to the problem. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Thanks for your responses guys. Especially to @Stelios Papamichail for providing the solution 3 months ago. [Firebase's response is not in a valid JSON format it seems](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69423519/13894931) It's a shame the official dev team hasn't taken notice of this. `jsonDecode(jsonEncode(event.snapshot.value)));` works perfectly. It's probably bad performance wise but I don't really care at this point I'm just happy it does. I don't know why it works either.

This now works perfectly

```
  Future<void> readProfileData({required String userId}) async {
    DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref("users/$userId");

    try {
      final DataSnapshot? snapShot = await ref.get();

      Map<String, dynamic> data = jsonDecode(jsonEncode(snapShot?.value));

      userProfile = UserProfile.fromMap(data);

      setGender(userProfile.gender);

      notifyListeners();

      log(userProfile.toString());
    } on Exception catch (e) {
      log(e.toString());
    }
  }
```

Hopefully more people see this and not waste their life like I have.

Comment: I have tested using jsonDecode(jsonEncode(event.snapshot.value)); but I still get [VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' when trying to map the data to my Model

Comment: This solved my issue also! Spent hours fighting the package! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is happening because `event.snapshot.value` is returning something that isn't expected by **Map.from**. Basically **Map.from** expects a **Map<dynamic, dynamic>** so you can cast your data as the same.

Try changeling your line to

```
final data = Map<String, dynamic>.from(event.snapshot.value as Map<dynamic, dynamic>);
```

Comment: Tried it, doesn't work. Same error. :(

Comment: Which one that is shown in image or <object?, object?> one?

Comment: Yeah `Unhandled Exception: type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<Object?, Object?>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>' in type cast`

Answer (score -1):

***Solution:***

if you have data in the FIREBASE DATABASE,
for example: [Please Click Here to Check ScreenShot](https://scontent.fisb17-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t39.30808-6/275624214_2102432426590018_7130118197254224223_n.png?_nc_cat=106&ccb=1-5&_nc_sid=730e14&_nc_ohc=uzDcghGYpdYAX9CXqXg&_nc_ht=scontent.fisb17-1.fna&oh=00_AT-pIDvo3iJzE_TFXqrohGBTyhSLtMKFhy8U0QXmZFb4Uw&oe=62325BA1)

***Then as of now, 12th March, 2022:***

To Retrieve Data from Firebase Database, you must use following sample code.

```
String name = (snap.snapshot.value as Map)["name"];
print("name :: $name");
```

**Check Complete Example with Full Sample Code:**
e.g: For retrieving name and email from database.
[Please click here to Check the Complete Code Sample Screenshot](https://scontent.fisb17-1.fna.fbcdn.net/v/t39.30808-6/275616988_2102439169922677_3994024596316528808_n.png?_nc_cat=102&ccb=1-5&_nc_sid=730e14&_nc_ohc=6CMSSxpUyTkAX9l8I7C&_nc_ht=scontent.fisb17-1.fna&oh=00_AT8fY8mq74pYRZYlc56vW_Mgp225itF_LXHfz9tak5hDvg&oe=62317672)