# '_InternalLinkedHashMap<Object?, Object?>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast

Tags: json, database, flutter, firebase

When trying to cast a value after reading a realtime firebase response, I get the error:

```
'_InternalLinkedHashMap<Object?, Object?>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>' in type cast
```

This only occurs for me with *realtime*, not *firestore*.

After days of digging, I found an answer for this but wanted to post this again because the error is quite frustrating.

I am new to stackoverflow so I am currently unable to comment on the answer given in the link:

[Can't cast _InternalLinkedHashMap<Object?, Object?> to anything](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70595225/cant-cast-internallinkedhashmapobject-object-to-anything)

Comment: Can you share a code snippet of where you're casting the data?

Comment: This is the answer that worked for me:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70595225/cant-cast-internallinkedhashmapobject-object-to-anything